# Reliable way of getting sender's email address using Redemption

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I have been getting the sender's email address in Outlook using the `RDOMail.SenderEmailAddress` property, but I have recently realised that under some cases for SMTP or IMAP email accounts, that this property is `null` occasionally, right after the email arrives the inbox.

There's a rather convoluted way to get the sender's email address using the Outlook Interop Library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff184624.aspx

However, this does not work with the Redemption `RDOMail` object because the `RDOAddressEntry` interface lacks the `AddressEntryUserType` and the `GetExchangeUser` method.

The documentation of the `RDOAddressEntry` object says the following about the `SMTPAddress` property:

> String, read-only. Returns the SMTP address of the given user. If the
>   address type is "SMTP", the returned value is the same as that
>   returned by the Address property. If the address type is "EX",
>   Redemption tries to retrieve the PR_SMTP_ADDRESS property, if
>   unsuccessful, it retrieves the default SMTP address from the
>   PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES Extended MAPI property.

Looks like it might be a more reliable way to get the sender's address if I do this in my method:

```
if (rdoMail.SenderEmailAddress != null) return rdoMail.SenderEmailAddress;
if (rdoMail.Sender != null) return rdoMail.Sender.SMTPAddress;
return null;
```

Since I don't have a reliable way to test my theory, I'm seeking help here to see if anyone has more experience in dealing with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot image why `SenderEmailAddress` would be null, unless you have a partially downloaded item (IMAP4 specific). There is no reason to have `AddressEntryUserType` or `GetExchangeUser` method - all you need is the address type - if it is "EX", you have a GAL user, otherwise an SMTP address.

To get the sender SMTP address, check the `SenderEmailType` property. If it is anything but "EX", just use the `SenderEmailAddress` property. If it is "EX", read the `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress` property using `RDOMail.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F"]`. If you get back null, check if `RDOMail.Sender` is not null and read the `RDOMail.Sender.SMTPAddress` property.